# How can I place 2 buttons next to each other in separate divs with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 separate boxes, which are links to other pages and at the bottom of each box I have a 'read more' button.

However because each box will have a different amount of text, this means the buttons are obviously not lining up next to each other.

My HTML code...

```
 <div class="row text-center">
    <a href="#" class="col-md-3 services">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <h4 class="service-heading">Website Design &amp; Development</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit. </p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More...</button>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="col-md-3 services">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <h4 class="service-heading">Hosting &amp; Domain Management</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read More...</button>
      </a>
</div>
```

I have created a pen which shows how I currently have this...

https://codepen.io/cjhill44/pen/OQNgxV

What I want is for the 2 'read more' buttons to sit next to each other.

Can anyone tell me how to align these buttons to that they both sit next to each other at the bottom of their respective divs. I don't really want to specify a fixed height for the boxes as that will mean changing it for each breakpoint.

I am using bootstrap and have tried lots of suggested solutions on here but none seem to resemble my specific issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on some bootstrap classes to create a flex layout inside services and use `margin-top:auto` with buttons with no need for extra CSS or HTML changes.

Check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) for more details about class utilities.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <a href="#" class="col-md-3 services d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
      <h4 class="service-heading">Website Design &amp; Development</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit. </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto">Read More...</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="col-md-3 services d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
      <h4 class="service-heading">Hosting &amp; Domain Management</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto">Read More...</button>
    </a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: That's really useful, thanks, and it works! Just what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap 4 you have an opportunity here to rely on `card-deck`.  `Card` is one of BS4s newest components and `card-deck` causes all the `cards` within to take on similar dimensions.  By placing your 'Read More...' link in `card-footer` you can ensure it's always at the bottom.

You can do all of this relying on native Bootstrap 4 classes with the exception of removing the default background from `card-footer`; that requires a new class.

```css
.bg-none {
  background: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card text-center border-0 bg-none">
    <a href="#" class="services card-body">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>

      <h4 class="service-heading">Website Design &amp; Development</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit. </p>
    </a>
    
    <div class="card-footer border-0 bg-none">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More...</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card text-center border-0">
    <a href="#" class="services card-body">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      
      <h4 class="service-heading">Hosting &amp; Domain Management</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
    </a>
    
    <div class="card-footer border-0 bg-none">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More...</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```